Use hashcat to appear Token length exception
Use the following command
.\hashcat.exe -m 14700 -a 3 "$itunes_backup$*10*2d16f580921a8b3be93153ae5ce8d67afbd47069243820bfbda466c0a47502310d0814b83533c789*10000*c3c5d99152c95656f6e1562e89d3be925fa47530*10000000*8255c56f660e3f5523a928ceddd4772274eb41f5" ?d?d?d?d

.\hashcat.exe -m 14800 -a 3 "$itunes_backup$*10*2d16f580921a8b3be93153ae5ce8d67afbd47069243820bfbda466c0a47502310d0814b83533c789*10000*c3c5d99152c95656f6e1562e89d3be925fa47530*10000000*8255c56f660e3f5523a928ceddd4772274eb41f5" ?d?d?d?d

I got the following error, why is that?

The graphics card used is Intel Core Graphics,The model is 【Inter(R) UHD Graphics 750】
How do I deal with this?

I've found the problem, "" shouldn't be used to include hash values, '' should be used
